# Can I use the Fast Hands bonus action to control Mage Hand?

Tags: spells, dnd-5e, rogue

My character is a level one high elf rogue, so I picked mage hand as his high elf cantrip. When he gets to level three, I plan on picking the Thief archetype.
 Can he use the fast hands bonus action to control the mage hand that he cast on a previous turn?

I think he should be able to because fast hands allows for the "use an object" action and I can't think of what other type of action controlling mage hand would be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mage Hand's description reads:

> You can **use your action** to control the hand. You can use the hand to manipulate an object, open an unlocked door or container, stow or retrieve an item from an open container, or pour the contents out of a vial.

Fast Hands:

> Starting at 3rd level, you can use the bonus action granted by your Cunning Action to make a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check, use your thieves’ tools to disarm a trap or open a lock, or take the Use an Object action.

Presumably, this newfound dexterity is proper to the Rogue (i.e., the physical prowess of the PC), whereas Mage Hand is based on mental effort and the limitations of the spell. Hence, without a houserule, I don't think you can control Mage Hand using a bonus action.

As [othniel2005](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/14899/othniel2005) said, you would have to pick the Arcane Trickster archetype for that.

Comment: Emphasizing "use your action" from the Mage Hand description implies that the fact that it's normally a full action means that it's not a bonus action in this case. It seems like you're actually trying to make a case that the specifics of Fast hands (which change this in some cases) does not apply in this case. Emphasis therefore seems misleading to me. (Also you've not entirely convinced *me* yet that "control the hand" (especially as that can be used to "manipulate an object") definitely doesn't fall under the "Use an Object" action... )

Answer (score 5):

Mage hand requires *using your action* to control it.

> You can use your action to control the hand. You can
>   use the hand to manipulate an object, open an unlocked
>   door or container, stow or retrieve an item from an open
>   container, or pour the contents out of a vial. You can
>   move the hand up to 30 feet each time you use it.

That means it's an action. generally unless something specifies *bonus* action in 5e, it requires an action to do (with the explicit exclusion of very minor things).

Fast hands does nothing to change this action economy as it only applies to "use an object" Mage hand is not this as it requires a full action to use.

Comment: Fast hands allows you to use actions that are normally full actions, as bonus actions. This completely changes the action economy of how these actions are used.

Comment: PHB 193 says "When an object requires your action for its use, you take the *Use an Object* action. This action is also useful when you want to interact with more than one object on your turn" - *Use an Object* *does* require a full action to use. Also, *Fast Hands* applies to other actions besides *Use an Object*...